# android .getResposeCode(); keeps throwing IO Exception even on valid URL

Tags: java, android, httpresponse, ioexception

I'm trying to verify if a web address exists through my program. The website does exist, but this method keeps throwing the IO Exception.

```
    try{
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(webAddress).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            return "good";
        else
            return "bad";
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "IOException thrown";
    }
```

Event though I know that the address exists, I double checked the response code using this website: http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/ , and it is responding 200 OK

thanks for the help

```
12-13 14:31:48.619  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-13 14:31:48.619  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
12-13 14:31:48.619  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
12-13 14:31:48.619  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
12-13 14:31:48.619  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
12-13 14:31:48.629  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
12-13 14:31:48.629  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
12-13 14:31:48.629  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
12-13 14:31:48.629  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
12-13 14:31:48.629  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
12-13 14:31:48.629  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
12-13 14:31:48.629  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
12-13 14:31:48.629  13123-13123/com.mmappz.catacase W/System.err﹕ at com.mmappz.catacase.StartScreen.checkCode(StartScreen.java:130)
```

Comment: What does the IOException say?

Comment: I updated with the section of the logcat with the error.

Comment: Please post the exception message and not just the stacktrace.